# Visa requirements for the US and Canada with South Africa-issued travel document

Tags: visas, usa, canada, refugees

I hold a Geneva Convention travel document PR from South Africa. Can I travel with it to Canada or America. I am from south African refugee. I hold a Geneva Convention travel document PR.

Answer (score 1):

With a South African refugee travel document, you can travel to Canada or the United States, but you require a visa first. You can read about that process for [Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eligibility.html) or [the US](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas.html). You may also need visas for any countries you transit on the way, and should research what rules apply.